# Does anyone here know if you can use the new asset modules inline like you could with say raw loader?

Tags: webpack

Does anyone here know if you can use the new asset modules inline like you could with say raw loader? like... `require('raw-loader-whatever.svg')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Re-reading the question, it looks like you're trying to find override syntax, so you could  configure `svg` as `type: asset` normally.